# Exporting oracle dump file to NAS server

Tags: oracle, export, dump, nas

Could anyone please help me to find a way to exporting oracle dump file to NAS server, 
I know how to export to the same server where oracle is working but not how to deal with exporting to remote NAS linux server.
Code for exporting schema from db.

```
DECLARE
  handle NUMBER;
  status VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  handle := dbms_datapump.open ('EXPORT', 'SCHEMA');
  dbms_datapump.add_file (handle, 'hr.dmp', 'BACK_UP');
  dbms_datapump.metadata_filter (handle, 'SCHEMA_EXPR', 'IN (''HR'')');
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle, 'INCLUDE_METADATA', 1); 
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle,  'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD',  'AUTOMATIC'); 
  dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle,  'ESTIMATE', 'BLOCKS'); 
  dbms_datapump.start_job (handle);
  dbms_datapump.wait_for_job (handle, status);

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- mount your NAS share on the server

2- create a directory which maps to the mount point of the NAS:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY NAS AS '/nas_share/datapump';
```

3- change the directory_name in your script:

```
  dbms_datapump.add_file (handle, 'hr.dmp', 'NAS');
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the path of the RMAN default path for your active channel:

e.g.

```
RMAN> configure channel device type disk format '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/backup/%U' maxpiecesize 8 G;
```

or

create or replace directory data_pump_dir as '/your/new/path/goes/here'

Comment: the op doesn't ask to backup to NAS using RMAN but using datapump.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO kind of goes hand in hand, anyways answer updated